# Issue with prolog recursion and incrementation

Tags: prolog

I'm having an issue converting minutes to number of hours and remainder of minutes using recursion, calculating the left over minutes works fine but I cant seem to calculate the hours:

```
mins_to_hours_and_mins(N, H, M):-
    N >= 60 ->  
    H1 = H + 1,
    N1 = N - 60,
    H = H1,
    mins_to_hours_and_mins(N1, H1, M).

mins_to_hours_and_mins(N, H, M):-
    N < 60 ->  
    H = H,
    M is N.
```

output of "mins_to_hours_and_mins(70, H, M).":

```
H = H+1,
M = 10
false
```

output of "mins_to_hours_and_mins(40, H, M).":

```
M = 40
```

Note: I must use recursion for this and I must have 2 rules and 3 parameters for the queries

Comment: Prolog does not use =/2 to assign the result of a math expression to a variable, it uses [is/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=is/2). So change statements like `H1 = H + 1` to `H1 is H + 1`.

Comment: Ive changed the statements to is instead of = and i get the error arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

Comment: This example exercise and the problem you have are very well documented in other StackOverflow answers, please search for the answer, it is easily found.

Comment: Also I would change [->/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=-%3E/2) to `,` (and)

Comment: Ive been searching for that issue about the arguments are not sufficiently instantiated and i can seem to find a solution

Comment: I am sure if you were in a video game trying to take down a boss you would try harder. You need to apply the same effort here.

Comment: Ive been on this issue for almost a week i genuinely don't understand why I get the error

Comment: Have you read and understood this Q&A: [Prolog convert mins to hours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54688256/1243762)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prolog convert mins to hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54688256/prolog-convert-mins-to-hours)

Comment: unfortunately no, I've read through that thread, but according to my task I am unable to use a solution that uses 4 parameters, i think this is why I've been stuck for so long on it.

Comment: Now we know what your problem is, `I am unable to use a solution that uses 4 parameters` Check with your instructor, because you are most likely misunderstanding the meaning of that. The requirement is probably that the query `mins_to_hours_and_mins/3` has to work. In the referenced Q&A that is also true, but it uses a helper predicate `mins_to_hours_helper/4` to do the real work. I seriously doubt that the instructor is not allowing helper predicates. If they are I would like to know who they are to understand why.

Comment: Basically we have to have 2 rules, one to work out the hours and one for the minutes, and we cannot use more than 3 parameters for the queries

Comment: Then you should put that in the question. We don't read minds.

Comment: Yeah true my bad

Comment: related question by OP: [Converting minutes to hours in prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60262036/1243762)